# nan in c++ for beginner

Tags: c++, nan, sqrt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float xstart = -2, xfinal = 2, h = 0.5;
    float t, y;

    cout << "X start = -2" << endl;
    cout << "X final = 2" << endl;
    cout << "step = 0.5" << endl << endl;

    for ( float x = xstart; x <= xfinal; x+= h)
    {
        t= sqrt(pow(sin(x),2)) / sqrt(x - 4);
        y= sqrt(2 * t + x);

        cout << x << " | " << t << " | " << y << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

This outputs t and y variables as nan. I am out of ideas on how to fix it. The code is just example of the problem, no need to do anything else than the fix nans.

Comment: The square root of a negative number is NAN.

Comment: The problem here is not C++. The problem here is basic math.

Comment: What do you think `sqrt(pow(sin(-2), 2)) / sqrt(-2 -4)` is as a float value? I'm fairly sure `float`s can't represent `-0.321*i`

Comment: Note that if you want a complex result, you should use [`std::complex` from the <complex> header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t= sqrt(pow(sin(x),2)) / sqrt(x - 4);
```

In C++, the square root of a negative number is defined as NAN, "Not a Number". Since the variable `x` iterates in the range `[-2, 2]`, you're never going to have this not be NAN, which means all calculations using it will arrive at NAN.

If you're expecting sqrt to return complex numbers, you'll need to make use of `std::complex` and its various math functions.

Comment: Thanks! My lecturer wants to make me fail badly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fixable as long as you continue to use negative numbers in the sqrt function. (Hint: x - 4 is always negative or zero)